# Why did my transaction fail? (BEP20 token in BSC)

Tags: solidity, transactions, testnets, bsc, binance

I just created a BEP20 token in Remix and deployed it on the BSC Testnet. When I try to transfer tokens from my Metamask account, give me this message in Transaccion Data:

> Transaction decoding is not available for chainId 97

Maybe this would be cause in the BSC Testnet isn't possible transactions? I really don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This StackExchange is focused on Ethereum and the question is BSC specific, therefore off-topic.

Regarding your question:
MetaMask uses information about the contracts and existing abis to decode the transaction data. If you deploy a new contract on a network that MetaMask does not support for transaction decoding you will see this message.

Transaction decoding just shows more information on the hex data to make sure that the user knows what they are signing. Even if this is not available on a specific network you can still execute the transaction.

If you already submitted a transaction and it failed, then you should share the transaction hash to that transaction so that it is possible to look into it. If you want to get support on this StackExchange I would also recommend to use one of the official Ethereum test networks (e.g. Rinkeby, Goerli, Ropsten or Kovan)